# How to load google library using google.load over an https connection

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to load a google maps library.
I have used below function for same.

```
google.load("maps", "3", {other_params: "libraries=places&sensor=false", "callback": mapsLoaded });
```

However on an https connection it return below error in console
[blocked] The page at 'https://mydomain.com?module=Contacts&action=index' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&sensor=false&callback=google.loader.callbacks.maps': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

How do I resolve above error ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem in your case is you're trying to load a google library using `google.load()` on an `SSL` encrypted page, whereas the libraries that you're pulling, their links are not 'secure'. From the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/loader/#GoogleLoad), you could simply try doing (i.e. load `jsapi` over **https**):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
//The libraries should now be loaded over https.
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("search", "1");
 google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
 google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>
```

I was checking [another blog post](http://joethewebguy.net/2011/how-to-use-google-jsapi-on-http-or-https-pages/) over loading google libraries over http/https and the author suggests checking the current page for http/https and modifying the DOM accordingly:

```
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”>

 var prot =((“https:” == document.location.protocol) ? “https://” : “http://”);
 var key = “INSERT-YOUR-KEY“;
 document.write(unescape(“%3Cscript src='” + prot + “www.google.com/jsapi?key=” + key + “‘      type=’text/javascript’%3E%3C/script%3E”));

</script>
```

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.